# Elasticsearch index creation with mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm struggling with the simple task of index creation, the goal is to create an index with an analyzer and a field mapping. When I create a index with an analyzer i can talk to the analyzer via the analyze api calls, but when I add the mapping information the create index calls fails with "Analyzer [analyzer1] not found for field [$field]]", I created a script to show the problem:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    INDEX_NAME="test1"

    echo "delete index just to be sure"
    curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/$INDEX_NAME/"; echo

    echo "create new index"
    curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/$INDEX_NAME/" -d '{
        "index":{
            "analysis":{
                "analyzer":{
                    "analyzer1":{
                        "type":"custom",
                        "tokenizer":"standard",
                        "filter":[ "standard", "lowercase", "stop", "kstem", "ngram" ]
                    }
                },
                "filter":{
                    "ngram":{
                        "type":"ngram",
                        "min_gram":2,
                        "max_gram":15
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }'; echo

    echo "analyze something with our shiny new analyzer"
    curl -XGET "localhost:9200/$INDEX_NAME/_analyze?analyzer=analyzer1&pretty=true" -d 'abcd'

    echo "remove the created index"
    curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/$INDEX_NAME/"; echo

    echo "create new index again with mapping"
    curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/$INDEX_NAME/" -d '{
        "index":{
            "analysis":{
                "analyzer":{
                    "analyzer1":{
                        "type":"custom",
                        "tokenizer":"standard",
                        "filter":[ "standard", "lowercase", "stop", "kstem", "ngram" ]
                    }
                },
                "filter":{
                    "ngram":{
                        "type":"ngram",
                        "min_gram":2,
                        "max_gram":15
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "product": {
                "properties": {
                    "title": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "search_analyzer" : "analyzer1",
                        "index_analyzer" : "analyzer1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }'; echo
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe your issue is that the `analysis` settings need to be nested within a `settings` node in your JSON, not within an `index` node as you have it. Please reference the [Elasticsearch Create Index API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) for details on constructing the JSON.

Therefore, your create index call should look like the the following:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/$INDEX_NAME/" -d '{
    "settings":{
        "analysis":{
            "analyzer":{
                "analyzer1":{
                    "type":"custom",
                    "tokenizer":"standard",
                    "filter":[ "standard", "lowercase", "stop", "kstem", "ngram" ]
                }
            },
            "filter":{
                "ngram":{
                    "type":"ngram",
                    "min_gram":2,
                    "max_gram":15
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "product": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "search_analyzer" : "analyzer1",
                    "index_analyzer" : "analyzer1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}';
```