# Getting error in Elasticsearch while creating index using postman

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-indices

I have installed Elasticsearch 5.1 in ubuntu 14.04. I have performed some operations in Elasticsearch like create index, delete index etc. Then I have installed Kibana 5.1. Now I want to create new index in elasticsearch using postman (localhost:9200/my_index with PUT). But I'm getting this error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "unknown setting [index.country] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "unknown setting [index.country] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I remember that I have used `country` as index or type. But then I have purged elasticsearch and kibana (also deleted directories related to those). Reinstalled both. But still getting this error. If anyone knows the solution, it will be appreciated.

Here is output of some query which may you need to solve issue.

**GET localhost:9200/_mapping**

> {   ".kibana": {
>       "mappings": {
>         "server": {
>           "properties": {
>             "uuid": {
>               "type": "keyword"
>             }
>           }
>         },
>         "config": {
>           "properties": {
>             "buildNum": {
>               "type": "keyword"
>             }
>           }
>         }
>       }   } }

**(GET) localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v**

> [   {
>       "health": "yellow",
>       "status": "open",
>       "index": ".kibana",
>       "uuid": "O_ORG0ONQNCEe8JU_C0SKQ",
>       "pri": "1",
>       "rep": "1",
>       "docs.count": "1",
>       "docs.deleted": "0",
>       "store.size": "3.1kb",
>       "pri.store.size": "3.1kb"   } ]

**(GET) localhost:9200/country**

> {   "error": {
>       "root_cause": [
>         {
>           "type": "index_not_found_exception",
>           "reason": "no such index",
>           "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
>           "resource.id": "country",
>           "index_uuid": "*na*",
>           "index": "country"
>         }
>       ],
>       "type": "index_not_found_exception",
>       "reason": "no such index",
>       "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
>       "resource.id": "country",
>       "index_uuid": "*na*",
>       "index": "country"   },   "status": 404 }

Comment: Are you sending a requestbody with the put request for index creation?

Comment: How're you doin the post, if you could show us ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply have a `PUT` request as such:

```
http://localhost:9200/indexname <--- give your index name
```

And then within your request body you could give the `mappings`:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "message_logs": {
      "properties": {
        "anyfield": { <-- give your field
          "type": "text" <-- and the type
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876857/elasticsearch-index-creation-with-mapping) might help you if you're willing to create the index using `CURL`.
The above is just a sample. You could reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem. My problem is to put code into the "Body" area, just detele that, the GET function would work.

> Same error message: {
> "error": {
> "root_cause": [
> {
> "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
> "reason": "request [GET /person/_doc/1] does not support having a body"
> }
> ],
> "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
> "reason": "request [GET /person/_doc/1] does not support having a body"
> },
> "status": 400 }